# Why navigation controller is nil even though I push it

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `LoginViewController` and want to push `MainTabBarController` 
So, I do this

```
let controller = MainTabBarController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

`LoginViewController` has a navigation controller but `MainTabBarController` doesn't for some reasons.

I have two questions, if my flow is  `LoginViewController` -> `MainTabBarController` -> `Other Controllers` embedded in `MainTabBarController`, and I want to log out, how do I get to the `LoginViewController` without memory leaks? I was thinking about something like `popToRootViewController` but not sure if it would work.

This is how I'm creating other controllers in `MainTabBarController`

```
private func createNewViewController(viewController: UIViewController, title: String, imageName: String) -> UIViewController {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationController?.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: title, image: UIImage(systemName: imageName), selectedImage: nil)
        navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .white
        viewController.navigationItem.title = title
        return viewController
    }
```

But it doesn't really work since navigationController is `nil`. I don't use storyboards at all though.

EDIT: Apparently embedding a `UITabBarController` inside a `UINavigationController` is not supported.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good design. If you push to MainVC from LoginVC won't the user be able to swipe back and go back to the LoginVC?

Comment: @Frankenstein thats what im thinking too

Answer (score 0):

Try this design. When `LoginVC` appears it checks if user is logged in and re-directs to `MainVC`. This is just a skelton, add more details as you go forward:

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = LoginVC()

        return true
    }
}

class LoginVC: UIViewController {

    var isUserLoggedIn = true

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        if isUserLoggedIn {
            present(MainVC(), animated: true)
        }
    }
}

class MainVC: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

        let firstVC = UIViewController()
        firstVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "firstVC", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)

        let secondVC = UIViewController()
        secondVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "secondVC", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)

        viewControllers = [firstVC, secondVC]
    }
}
```